# Select data where data between error ORA-00937

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get the number of people by date.

I've got this error:

> ORA-00937 not a single-group group function

the query is the following

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATA,count(PERSON)
FROM table
where DATA  >= TO_DATE ('01/05/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND DATA <= TO_DATE ('31/05/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
GROUP BY DATA
ORDER BY DATA
```

I don't understand what is wrong?

Comment: No need for DISTINCT, since your GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Comment: Remove distinct in select.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the semicolon at the end of the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT t.DATA, count(PERSON)
FROM table t
WHERE t.DATA  >= DATE '2016-05-01' AND t.DATA <= DATE '2016-05-31'
GROUP BY t.DATA
ORDER BY t.DATA;
```

Notes:

- `SELECT DISTINCT` is almost never needed with `GROUP BY`.
- I prefer dates in ANSI/ISO standard format of YYYY-MM-DD.  Oracle supports this with the `DATE` keyword.
- I recommend using table aliases and qualified column names.
- In Oracle, be careful with date comparisons.  If you want data from May, then `t.DATA  >= DATE '2016-05-01' AND t.DATA < DATE '2016-06-01'` is safer.  Dates could have time components.